# Extract text from PDF files in different orientations

Tags: python, pdf, text-extraction

I have few hundreds of PDF files I want to anonymize in Python with NLP. My anonymization function works on PDFs that are in 'normal' (vertical) orientation, I am however struggling with handling PDFs that are rotated clockwise or counterclockwise in a horizontal orientation. Some PDFs are scanned pages. Is there a way to read these PDFs the correct way so that the text is correctly extracted for anonymization?

```
    with fitz.open(input_file_path) as pdf_document:
        num_pages = pdf_document.page_count
        for page_number in range(num_pages):
            page = pdf_document.load_page(page_number)
            pdf_txt += page.get_text()

    anonymized_text = anonymize(pdf_txt)

    with open(output_file_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as txt_file:
        txt_file.write(anonymized_text)
```

I came across a method with pytesseract where the PDF file first needs to be converted to an image in order to check the orientation and rotate. This does however not seen very efficient to me, so I was wondering if any one of you knows another method. Thanks in advance!

Comment: PyMuPDF (fitz) text extraction has no problem with rotated text and simply extracts it. If the page itself is rotated, things are trivial anyway. If only some text is rotated, but not everything, then the only potential issue is (understandably) the text output sequence. If a OCR engine has recognized rotated text, then it depends on how good it has done that: if the OCR did not understand that it is recognizing rotated text, things are becoming less predictable.